# Can we use "and" without "both" in this case: "I like pizza and sushi"?

Tags: word-usage

For some reason it sounds somewhat incomplete for me, in comparison to "I like *both* pizza and sushi." But I don't think the nuance is the same, though I can't verbalize it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It _could_ be misunderstood as meaning that you like to eat them together, though obviously common sense suggests otherwise.

Comment: I see, thanks. Would you say this is more specific to this case, because things can be eaten together, or that it is more general, like using only "and" could mean that the referenced things should be considered one unit, while using "both...and" would make it clear that they are still separate things just being referenced together?

Comment: Well, it applies particularly to foods because many popular meals consist of two items (fish and chips, bacon and egg etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect of adding "both" is to emphasize that you like each of them, but not to the exclusion of the other, as if you were answering a question that seemed to expect a single answer:

> Q. So, do you like pizza, or sushi?
> A. I like both pizza and sushi. Do I have to choose?

On the other hand, if someone asked

> Q. What are your favorite foods?
> A. I like pizza and sushi.

In that case, it's better to omit *both*.